# Is ASP.NET Web Forms source code available for download anywhere?

Tags: asp.net

I noticed this site http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/. Is web forms source available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVC4ASPNETWebAPIAndASPNETWebPagesV2RazorNowAllOpenSourceWithContributions.aspx), no. Web Forms is part of the base classes, so they are only updated with .NET releases.

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't. Only ASP.NET MVC 4, Web API and Razor 2 as Scott Gu explained in [his blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/03/27/asp-net-mvc-web-api-razor-and-open-source.aspx).

Scott Hanselman answers [your question](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVC4ASPNETWebAPIAndASPNETWebPagesV2RazorNowAllOpenSourceWithContributions.aspx):

> **Why isn't ASP.NET Web Forms open sourced?**
>
> The components that are being open sourced at this time are all
>   components that are shipped independently of the core .NET framework,
>   which means no OS components take dependencies on them. Web Forms is a
>   part of System.Web.dll which parts of the Windows Server platform take
>   a dependency on. Because of this dependency this code can't easily be
>   replaced with newer versions expect when updates to the .NET framework
>   or the OS ships.

Answer (score 2):

No.It is not. [Here is why](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVC4ASPNETWebAPIAndASPNETWebPagesV2RazorNowAllOpenSourceWithContributions.aspx)

> **Why isn’t ASP.NET Web Forms open sourced?**
>
> The components that are being open sourced at this time are all
>   components that are shipped independently of the core .NET framework,
>   which means no OS components take dependencies on them. Web Forms is a
>   part of System.Web.dll which parts of the Windows Server platform take
>   a dependency on. Because of this dependency this code can’t easily be
>   replaced with newer versions expect when updates to the .NET framework
>   or the OS ships.